# Upgrade to Spring Boot 1.3 causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Running the test, the stack trace is entirely in the Spring framework and jUnit:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.setBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.registerApplicationEventMulticaster(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:329)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

The test class is pretty simple:

```
package com.uss.identity.dao;

import com.uss.identity.TestApplication;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;

@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiredMembersInspection")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {TestApplication.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ActiveProfiles("test-flyway")
public class ClientRepoTest2 {

    @Autowired
    ClientRepository dao;

    @Test
    public void testFindNone() throws Exception {
        assertNull(dao.findOne("nonesuch"));
    }

}
```

And the referenced TestApplication class is just:

```
package com.uss.identity;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@SpringBootApplication
@Profile({"test", "test-flyway"})
public class TestApplication {

}
```

This worked fine when using Spring Boot 1.2.8.RELEASE.  But trying to upgrade to 1.3.0.RELEASE causes the above exception.

Comment: This is testing a subclass of org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository  .  What's puzzling is that the exception is thrown on an interface that declares the method - at least in the presumed version of spring-core: 4.2.3.RELEASE.  I expected that I'd see a concrete implementation class listed in the exception...

Comment: Conflicting versions of spring jars. Do a `mvn dependency:tree` and check your dependencies make sure they are all the same version.

Answer (score 6):

You should use Spring Boot's dependency management to ensure that you get a consistent and correct version for all Spring Framework modules. You can do that either by using `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your pom's parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

or by importing it in your pom's `<dependency-management>` section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

More information is available in the [dependency management section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven) of the Spring Boot documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the culprit was activemq-all.jar which was bundling old spring classes.
Found that out with -verbose:class flag.

[Loaded org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BeanFactoryLocator from file:/C:/XXX/activemq-all-5.11.3.jar]
[Loaded org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator from file:/C:/XXX/activemq-all-5.11.3.jar]
[Loaded org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator from file:/C:/XXX/activemq-all-5.11.3.jar]

Comment: What is the activemq version that you switched to that fixed the problem?

Comment: We changed the sequence of classpath to prefer spring jars ahead of same activemq-all jar